# Flutter: Images go off device screen. SafeArea won't work

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make sure the UI will be fit and aligned to the screen correctly in most devices that will use my app. In particular, images, which I found getting off screen on my phone, but in the emulator it's exactly fit. As you can see in the images:

In Android Emulator:

[image: Here]

On my phone:

[image: Here]

This is my code:

```
class NewsTextScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const NewsTextScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final newsTexts = ref.watch(newsTextsProvider);

    return newsTexts.when(
      data: (newsTextsList) => ListView.builder(
        itemCount: newsTextsList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return SafeArea(
              top: true,
              bottom: true,
              left: true,
              right: true,
              child: Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              maxWidth: 100,
              maxHeight: 150,
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(45),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                  end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  colors: [
                    Color.fromRGBO(255, 191, 112, 1),
                    Color.fromRGBO(132, 159, 255, 1),
                  ],
                ),
      color: const Color(0xfffeb15c),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
      border: Border.all(width: 5.0, color: Colors.orange),
    ),
            child: Stack(
              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  bottom: -46,
                  right: -38,
                  child: Text(newsTextsList[index].date, textAlign: TextAlign.center,)
                  ),
                Positioned(
                  right: -35,
                  top: -45,
                  child: ConstrainedBox(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      maxHeight: 100,
                      maxWidth: 240
                    ),
                    child: Text(newsTextsList[index].paragraph, textAlign: TextAlign.justify,softWrap: true, ),
                ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  right: 207,
                  top: -42.5,
                  child: ConstrainedBox(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                        maxHeight: 135,
                        maxWidth: 240
                    ),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                        size: Size.fromRadius(70),
                        child: SafeArea(
                          top: true,
                          bottom: true,
                          left: true,
                          right: true,
                          child: CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: newsTextsList[index].img),
                      ),
                      )
                    )
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          )
          );
        },
      ),
      error: (error, stacktrace) {
        return Text(
          error.toString(),
        );
      },
      loading: () => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  `clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,` But based on your UI, you should use different approach with Row. and the issue is occurring because on emulator -38px ok and your device isnt.

```dart
child: Container(

//  ....
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      ConstrainedBox(
          constraints:
              BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 135, maxWidth: 240),
          child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                size: Size.fromRadius(70),
                child: SafeArea(
                  top: true,
                  bottom: true,
                  left: true,
                  right: true,
                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                      imageUrl: newsTextsList[index].img),
                ),
              ))),
      Expanded(
        child: Text( /// wrap with Padding if needed
          newsTextsList[index].paragraph,
          textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
          softWrap: true,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: Didn't work. It made things worse actually because I'm trying to position the layout in an organized way, just like in the pictures. When I don't use Positioned() widgets will be mixed everywhere.

Comment: for that you just need to use Padding and SizedBox on row